Modifying GML with xlink:href attributes to simple GML
I have a application-specific GML file that has non-GML tags (I mean geometry tags invented by the application experts).
I do not want to read the gml and convert it to python objects or WKT.
I just want to read the GML and whenever a tag has a xlink:href attribute that point to another element of the GML file, I copy and paste the element in the right place and convert the GML file to a simple file without href attributes.
I can write a function to do it. But it will increase the probablity of error. I was wondering if there is any python library or tool that can do it?
This is an example of the input GML and desired output file:
Input GML:
 <abc:Building gml:id="SearsTower">
     <abc:height>52</abc:height>
     <abc:position xlink:type="Simple" xlink:href="#p21"/>
 </abc:Building>
 <abc:SurveyMonument gml:id="g234">
     <abc:position>
         <gml:Point gml:id="p21">
             <gml:posList>100,200</gml:posList>
         </gml:Point>
     </abc:position>
 </abc:SurveyMonument>



output:
 <abc:Building gml:id="SearsTower">
     <abc:height>52</abc:height>
     <abc:position xlink:type="Simple">
         <gml:Point gml:id="p21">
             <gml:posList>100,200</gml:posList>
         </gml:Point>
     </abc:position>
 </abc:Building>
 <abc:SurveyMonument gml:id="g234">
     <abc:position>
         <gml:Point gml:id="p21">
             <gml:posList>100,200</gml:posList>
         </gml:Point>
     </abc:position>
 </abc:SurveyMonument>


I know that python GDAL library by OSGeo can read a gml file with href attribute. But I was not able to read my gml with that and create an output with the same tags just resolving the complication caused by href.
Even a command that converts it to resolved href version is good for me. I mean this part of the GDAL GML driver page:

I used this command, but it produced nothing!!!:
ogr2ogr -f GML output.gml input_data.gml --config GML_SKIP_RESOLVE_ELEMS NONE

Should I add something to this command or it is because my GML file has strange tags for GDAL?
this is one of the GML files:
https://registry.iho.int/productspec/view.do?idx=74&product_ID=S-123&statusS=5&domainS=ALL&category=product_ID&searchValue=
Then we download  S-123_EN_SampleData_Ed1.0.0.zip
and then, JSNPI123EX_A0001.GML
And the python script is calling the command in fact:
import subprocess 


input_gml = r"C:\...JSNPI123EX_A0001.GML"
output_gml = r"C:\... output.gml" 


command = [ 'ogr2ogr', '-f', 'GML',  output_gml,  input_gml, '--config', 'GML_SKIP_RESOLVE_ELEMS', 'NONE'] 


subprocess.run(command, check=True) 


But I have this error while I run the python script:
command ... returned non-zero exit status 3221225725

When I run the command directly in CMD, it takes 3 seconds and it shows no error but it produces no file!!
I ran it as admin.

Surely you want GDAL to resolve the elements? Can you give an example of the pythion code and a small full GML file and the output from the progeam.

Yes, I just want to have a GML without href. But I want to apply the effect of href before removing it.

The example you have in the question doesn't match with the example file (xlinks not simple for example); not sure too whether your desired exported XML would be valid GML as you'd end up with duplicate id's.  For XML parsing in python you may be better off using lxml

can lxml automatically find "href-ed" elements and return the full hierarchy of tags when I search for an element? or any other package?

Ah sorry, I assumed you had actual python code using the gdal API not a simple sub process call

lxml can parse an XML structure/patterns/xpaths and do link resolution
